# python Loop through a list and look for uniques

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a script here that grabs a csv and in one column it's just names colors.

How do you loop through a lists and grab unique items (remove duplicates)?

**Current output:**
Black,
blue,
blue,
red,
red,
green

**desired output:**
black,
blue,
red,
green

In my code, i've somehow managed a continues for loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import sys
import argparse

# creates a text file of all the colors in pipe seperated format
# parsing command line options
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='desc', description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input file', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', help='Output file', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'), default=sys.stdout)
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
# Declare variables from input
inf, outf = args.input, args.output
outf = csv.writer(outf)

print 'Loading %s file into memory' % inf.name
data = []
needle = ''
for i, line in enumerate(csv.reader(inf).next()):
    needle = line[11]
    if len(data) == 0:
        data.append(needle)
        continue
    j = 0
    for j, item in enumerate(data):
        print item
        if needle == item:
            print 'match'
            continue
        else:
            print 'no match: appending item'
            data.append(item)
            continue
```

Comment: Does your code not work, or are you just looking for better options? (Better how?)  If your code doesn't do exactly what you want, can you post some input/output examples?

Comment: @chrisjlee you keep using enumerate for nothing like in your yesterday's post :-/

Comment: @Boud Good point i fixed it up. Thanks for the tip btw. I had to use the previous method in the yesterday's to print the header btw. But today's question would be a good use of your tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `set()`. Take a look at this simple example, I guess this is what you want:

```
>>> list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list2=[4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> sett=set(list1).union(set(list2))
>>> print(sett)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have 2 lists.  You only have one list, line[11], which at each row you check the entire results list if you have seen it before before adding to your result.  This will give O(n2) run time and if your lists are larger you will notice it.  Set notation has already been suggested:

```
data = set()
for row in csv.reader(inf).next():
    data.add(row[11])
```

The only downside is that this is not stable.  If you need to maintain order, you just need a couple extra steps.

```
data = []
for row in csv.reader(inf).next():
    data.append(row[11])

result = []
for entry in data:
    if entry not in result: result.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use set?

```
data = set()

for i, line in enumerate(csv.reader(inf)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    data.add( line[11] )
```

In your code I can't find the reason why you need to iterate over 2 loops(?)
If you need to have list, you can just convert set to list: data = list(data)

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the lists to sets, and pulling out the unique items:

```
a = set(list1)
b = set(list2)
unique_items = a - b #or b - a depending on how you define unique
```